# How to reflect the current value in a drop-down field after populating options in a select control(ng-options) in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The discussion revolves around an application which can be visualized as,

[image]

As seen clearly, as the user clicks on one of the stories on the left hand side, the right-hand side fields are populated with the content corresponding to that story.

Every ***story*** has a ***title*** and a ***status***,

***service:***

```
myModule.service('AngelloModel', function(){

    var service = this;
    var stories = [
                {
                    title: 'First story',
                    status: 'To Do',

                },
                {
                    title: 'Second story',
                    status: 'Back Log',                     
                },
                {
                    title: 'Another story',
                    status: 'Code Review',                      
                }               
        ];
    var statuses = [
                  {name: 'Back Log'},
                  {name: 'To Do'},
                  {name: 'In Progress'},
                  {name: 'Code Review'},
                  {name: 'QA Review'},
                  {name: 'Verified'},
                  {name: 'Done'}
              ];

    service.getStories =  function(){
        return stories;
    }

    service.getStatuses = function(){
        return statuses;
    }       
})
```

***factory( a helper/utility function):***

```
myModule.factory('AngelloHelper', function() {

    var buildIndex = function(array, property) {
        var tempArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            tempArray[array[i][property]] = array[i];
        }

        return tempArray;
    }
    return {
        buildIndex : buildIndex
    }
})
```

***controller and module:***

```
var myModule = angular.module('Angello',[]);

myModule.controller('MainCtrl',function(AngelloModel, AngelloHelper){

    var main = this;

    main.stories = AngelloModel.getStories();
    main.statuses = AngelloModel.getStatuses();

    main.statusesIndex = AngelloHelper.buildIndex(main.statuses, 'name');

    main.setCurrentStory = function(story){

        main.currentStory = story;
        //alert(story.status);  // (To Do) if I click on first story

        main.currentStatus = main.statusesIndex[story.status];
        //alert(main.currentStatus); // {name: 'To Do'} if I click on first story
        //alert(main.currentStatus.name); // hence it will be (To Do)
    }
})
```

***html:***

```
<body>
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h2>Stories</h2>
                <div class="callout" ng-repeat="story in main.stories" 
                            ng-click="main.setCurrentStory(story)">
                    <h4>{{story.title}}</h4>
                    <p>{{story.description}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 content">
                <h2>Story</h2>
                <form class="form-horizontal">                  
                    <div class="form-group">                        
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputTitle">Title</label>                         
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
     id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="main.currentStory.title" />
                        </div>                          
                    </div>                      
                    <div class="form-group">    
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select id="inputStatus" class="form-control"
                            ng-model="main.currentStatus.name"
                            ng-options="l.name for l in main.statuses"></select>
                    </div>    
                </div>                      
                </form>                                         
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

***Consider this one which is the whole point of discussion :***

```
<select id="inputStatus" class="form-control"
                                ng-model="main.currentStatus.name"
                                ng-options="l.name for l in main.statuses"></select>
```

In the figure at the top, you can see the values in the drop-down field, which is done by

> ng-options="l.name for l in main.statuses"

However, the current value is not reflected on selecting a story, even though I have done,

> ng-model="main.currentStatus.name"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the ng-model you are trying to assign `name` as the unique identifier for options, so you may want to use `select as` i.e

```
  ng-options="l.name as l.name for l in main.statuses"
```

This will make sure the `ng-model` (`ng-model="main.currentStatus.name"`) is populated with the right name and your dropdown will be preselected with the value set in the ng-model property.

However if you are setting an object with array of objects as this with just one property you might as well set a unique identifier (if name is not one) or just use array of names.

Also with this you can removing the mapping logic (`main.statusesIndex = AngelloHelper.buildIndex(main.statuses, 'name');`) and just do:

```
 main.currentStatus = {name: story.status};
```

or even set your `ng-model` as

```
 <select id="inputStatus" class="form-control"
                        ng-model="main.currentStatus"
                        ng-options="l.name as l.name for l in main.statuses">  
 </select>
```

and

```
 main.currentStatus = story.status;
```

Comment: Even though it solved the problem, but I just didn't get it. Why do I need to write 'l.name as' even though l.name for l in main.statuses" results in the correct value.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari That is what will be set as ng-model, otherwise your ng-model needs to be exact object reference of status which is inconvinient in most cases. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#usage

Comment: Any suggestions on why it works too if I left ng-options as it is and further put ng-model="main.currentStatus". It works in this case, even though main.currentStatus is an object.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari That is because you are returning the same object reference in your mapping logic. However you can completely get rid of mapping logic and just do:  `main.currentStatus = {name: story.status};` or even change the ngmodel to `main.currentStatus` and `main.currentStatus = story.status`

Comment: What do you mean by mapping logic. Please extend a bit.

Comment: Why do you even need `main.statusesIndex = AngelloHelper.buildIndex(main.statuses, 'name');` This is what i meant by mapping logic. Please read my previous comment

Comment: It wasn't  developed by me.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Thank you once again.